# Jenkins - Send Email using a different sender according to the build status (successfull or failled)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I manage to send email according to the build status, select different recipients, but I am not able to figure out how to select a different user.

Has anyone come accross such requirement or an idea on how this could be achieved?

I tried with a groovy script but no luck so far.

Configure the SMTP plugging

Use a pipeline but did not figure out if a *emailext from* similar to the *emailext to* exists.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the official documentation of Jenkins it should be doable.

You could use the post actions to determinate the status of the running build. The Jenkins build status can be next: **Aborted, Failed, Stable, Successful and Unstable**. [Jenkins documentation - Build Status](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#build-status)

Once you implemented the post actions based on the status, you can create the actions needed at your convenience, in your case, to send a mail.

Following your case, you can use the emailext as you mention, according to the documentation, there's the possibility to add the optional parameter **from**. [Email Extension Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/).

Said that, your pipeline may look something like this (if declarative syntax):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('No-op') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        success {
            mail to: 'team@example.com',
             from: 'successTeam@example.com',
             subject: "Succesfull Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
             body: "All went fine with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
        }
        failure {
            mail to: 'team@example.com',
             from: 'failedTeam@example.com',
             subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
             body: "Something is wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}"
        }
    }
}
```

Please, keep in mind this is an example based on documentation but hopefully it gave you a hint in how to best approach to your needs.